# How to overcome "thin border" issue when using Flood Fill 4 algorithm?

Tags: java, flood-fill

I am writing an application that implements Flood Fill 4 algorithm. It works perfectly fine as long as the borders are thick. The algorithm fills in a certain color within the boarder. I tried to make the boarder thinner, but in that case the pixels were able to went out the boarder, and the program crashed.

[image]

Flood fill algorithm works EXCELLENT within the "thick boarder" area, which is the right triangle. However, the algorithm does not work within the other four areas because the boarders are thin, i.e. leakage takes place. Except for making the other boarders thick, are there any methods I can use?

Here is the complete code, it is just one class:

```
   import java.awt.Color;
   import java.awt.Container;
   import java.awt.Image;
   import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
   import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import javax.swing.JLabel;
   public class MyPolygon extends JFrame {
private JLabel my;

private BufferedImage buffered;

public MyPolygon() throws InterruptedException {
    createMy();
}
private void createMy() throws InterruptedException {
    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    contentPane.setSize(1200, 900);

    my = new JLabel();
    my.setIcon(new ImageIcon("myImage.png"));
    my.setBounds(10,200, 1000, 800);
    contentPane.add(my);

    setSize(1200, 900);
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    Image img = ((ImageIcon) my.getIcon()).getImage();
    buffered = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null),
            img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    buffered.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);


    int fill = 100;
    boundaryFill4(200, 215, fill, 50);
    my.setIcon(new ImageIcon(buffered));
}

// Flood Fill method
public void boundaryFill4(int x, int y, int fill, int boundary) {


    Color c = new Color(buffered.getRGB(x, y));
    int current = c.getRed();
    System.out.println(x + " " + y + " | " + current);

    if ((current > boundary) && (current != fill)) {
        int red = fill;
        int green = fill;
        int blue = fill;
        c = new Color(red, green, blue);
        buffered.setRGB(x, y, c.getRGB());

        boundaryFill4(x + 1, y, fill, boundary);
        boundaryFill4(x - 1, y, fill, boundary);
        boundaryFill4(x, y + 1, fill, boundary);
        boundaryFill4(x, y - 1, fill, boundary);
    }
}
// Main method
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    MyPolygon my = new MyPolygon();
    my.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
 }
```

Comment: @Lee Meador I have inserter the FULL code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` needs some work and you have no end condition on the recursion except for the colors.

**1**

The function `boundaryFill4` needs to look for x and y being small (top or left edge of picture) or large (bottom or top edge). It will look like this:

```
if (x < 0 || x > 200 || y < 0 || y > 200) {
    return;
}
```

**2**

If you look closely at the image, you can see that the edges of the border line (particularly when thin) uses faded pixels to keep the line from looking too jaggy. It's a smoothing technique.

One debugging tip is to add a short time delay to the top of the `boundaryFill4` function so you can see the process happening. It should show you where the fill is escaping and you can look at that spot blown up to get more clues.

The test currently looks for a pixel that has more RED in it than level 50 but isn't the same RED as the fill color.

The white in the center probably has all three RGB levels at the full value.

The border has pixels with all three RGB colors seemingly near 0 but the smoothing technique causes it to put higher values of RGB in some pixels to hide the jaggies. Be sure to check what colors levels the border actually is when its thin. Maybe the center pixels of the line are brighter than you think.

The fill color is a sort of dark grey.

- The code will find the white with the rule for "above 50 in RED".
- The code will avoid redoing already filled ones with the rule for "not RED == fill"
- What it does on the smoothed out border is up in the air. My guess is that there is a place where the lighter parts of the border are brighter than 50 (in RED)

Here are some ideas:

1. Change the rule to look at all three colors, not just red, when comparing to the fill color. (red==fill, green==fill and blue==fill) This might not help.
2. Perhaps you could pass the color of the starting point in and use it to compare instead of just filling everything brighter than 50. Either look for an exact color match or look for a close-enough match where the point is within 10 of the passed in original color.
3. If that doesn't work, use the delay to see what is unique about the places where it escapes.

Comment: I am sorry for confusion. My .jpg file consists of several sections: http://www.abcteach.com/free/p/polygon0303rgb.jpg It is a black and white polygon. The problem is not that pixels leak out of the canvas...The problem is that those pixels leak out to the adjacent section. I can thicken the boarders of the sections and that solves the problem...but it would look nasty, i.e. not that neat

Comment: Does that image have thick or thin borders? Could I see one with the other width borders?

Comment: the link is: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41007907/myIm.png   I transformed one segment (thickened the boearder), and it works there. However, the algorithm doesn't work in the other four regions

Comment: I inserted the image in my own answer above. Please, take a look.

Comment: You can edit your original question to add that picture and your text. It would be the normal way to do it here. I have another question. Can you post the code that decides, when its on one particular pixel, which neighboring pixels to add to the list (or stack) of adjacent pixels to do next?